# HTML Form submission and handling in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

i need a help. actually i have a html form as sown below.

```
<form id="blog" class="" action="blog/save" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="blog[title]" class="" name="blog[title]" value="" />
    <input type="text" id="blog[tag]" class="" name="blog[tag]" value="" />
    <textarea id="blog[editor]" class="" name="blog[editor]"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="blog[save]" name="blog[save]" class="button" value="Save Post" />
    <input type="submit" id="blog[savePub]" name="blog[savePub]" class="button" value="Save & Publish Post" />
</form>
```

but in the php file i need to check which submit button is clicked blog['save'] or blog['savePub']. and i tried like this

```
if ($_REQUEST['blog[save]']) {
       echo $_POST['blog[title]'];
} 
else if($_REQUEST['blog[savePub]') {
       echo $_POST['blog[title]'];
}
```

but i am getting an error **Notice: Undefined index: blog[save]**

please help me to find a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance...
Wishes and Prayers..
Jaison Justus

Comment: The `id=` attribute should only contain alphanumeric values, no square brackets. (The `name=` however may.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if (isset($_POST['blog']['savePub']))
   echo $_POST['blog']['editor'];
```

Comment: if (isset($_POST['blog']['save'])) {
   $blog = $_POST['blog']['title'];
}. the isset is not working. but can access $_POST['blog']['title'] outside the if condition.

Comment: then they clearly clicked the savePub button, not the save button

Comment: try to change it to if (isset($_REQUEST['blog']['savePub']))
Edit: Or maybe @tobyodavies is right, and the clicked on the savePub button :)

Answer (score 1):

when you use `[` and `]` in html form names PHP conveniently transforms them into sub arrays so you'll find your data at `$_POST['blog']['title']` and `$_POST['blog'][savePub']` etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
if (isset($_POST['blog']['save'])) {
       echo $_POST['blog']['title'];
} 
else if(isset($_POST['blog']['savePub'])) {
       echo $_POST['blog']['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (isset($_POST['blog']['save'])) {
       echo $_POST['blog']['title'];
} 
else{
       echo $_POST['blog']['title'];
}
```